# How to get jpg image from heic format in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am picking photos from gallery and upload to server but since few days I noticed that some photos have extension heic and browsers can't render those images.
1. Is there a way to extract photos from uploaded heic?
2. How in react native I can get jpeg from this format?

Comment: Which lib are you using to fetch images on device?

Answer (score 11):

You can convert it on the server side, with the help of this awesome lib **Tifig**.

https://github.com/monostream/tifig

You can also use API's like https://cloudconvert.com/formats/image/heic to convert either on server side or on the mobile (client side).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker), which is the community library and most used one.

Actually is not necessary to install another module, just grab always the `uri` from the response and update the filename in case you are having a *heic* image. Code example:

```
const options = {
    title: 'Select Avatar',
    storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images'
    },
    noData: true,
    quality: 1,
    mediaType: 'photo'
};

ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, imgResponse => {

    this.setState({ imageLoading: true, avatarMediaId: null });

    if ((imgResponse.didCancel) || (imgResponse.error)) {
        this.setState({ imageLoading: false });
    } else {
        let source = {};
        let fileName = imgResponse.fileName;
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && (fileName.endsWith('.heic') || fileName.endsWith('.HEIC'))) {
            fileName = `${fileName.split(".")[0]}.JPG`;
        }
        source = { uri: imgResponse.uri, fileName };
        this.uploadImage(source);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution before and were you successful?

Comment: Hey, yes! I still have it in production. It's impressive that it works, can't remember where I've read about this workaround, sorry.

Comment: "Try setting forceJpg:true, then when you get the image response back, use the path property instead of sourceURL to get the jpg. sourceURL will be the original HEIC." from: 
https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/720#issuecomment-518776885

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution: I am using react-native-image-crop-picker.

In my case, the server doesn't accept if a filename is .HEIC, telling me to use .png or .jpg 
So I just:

```
image.filename.replace(/HEIC/g, 'jpg')
```

To give you a whole picture:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', {
  uri: image.path,
  name: image.filename.replace(/HEIC/g, 'jpg'),
  type: image.mime,
});

return await axios.post(`/avatar/${id}`, formData);
```

Comment: Changing the extension does not change the image format.