# Convert HEIC to image format Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Has anyone use heic2any to convert HEIC file to image format ? I added module and it working fine when i'm in localhost environment. but when i use yarn build to build project in production environment it'll get error "Blob is not define". Please help me . Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+heic2any+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Also have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851807/how-to-get-jpg-image-from-heic-format-in-react-native/48900997